# Powerbuilder dataprocessing error?

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm fairly new to Powerbuilder and I am having this issue during run time. When I run my program it shows this error:

```
999 Cannot connect!
DBMS is not supported in your current installation
```

What's the cause of this?

Comment: What DBMS are you trying to connect to? Have you insured all database drives and prerequisites are installed?

Answer (score 7):

You're not populating the transaction object correctly.  Somewhere in your code you are doing something like `SQLCA.DBMS = "XXX"`  where XXX is the first three characters of your database interface, e.g., `SQLCA.DBMS = "ODB"` for ODBC or `SQLCA.DBMS = "ORA"` for Oracle.

The fact the message reads

```
DBMS is not supported in your current installation
```

versus

```
DBMS XXX is not supported in your current installation
```

indicates the DBMS property is being set to an empty string. Many applications use `ProfileString` to grab this value from an INI file, so it's likely the value is not in the INI file or (more likely) that the INI file is not being located by your application at runtime.